# Event Based react native background

Tags: android, gps, react-native

Is it possible to implement an event based background service that runs when the app has been left? I am planning to use react-native and their implementation of geolocation. The device will be an Android Phone. It would be a plus if the same goals can be made available on iOS too. I have heard that iOS have strict guidelines of GPS running in background service when user has left the active app state.

EDIT: Further research shows that I may be able to implement this with cordova plugin. Although I have no experience with working with this plugin before.

Comment: You can do that in the native part of the app just like how you do it on android and iOS natively and then use the native module bridge to update your views in react native if needed.

Comment: @abeikverdi So i would have to do native coding for both platform and do a custom component (as a component bridge) with react native. So there is no build in tools with react-native to achieve this?